# ALT + s does not work with IE selenium driver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

As the title states I'm using the IE driver for Selenium

I am trying to save a file automatically when I get prompted on a site with ALT + s

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

ie_options = Options()
ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True

ie_driver = ie_loc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = webdriver.Ie(ie_driver, options=ie_options)
    driver.get(url_loc)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    time.sleep(5)
    combine_keys = ActionChains(driver)
    combine_keys.key_down(Keys.ALT).key_down('s').perform()
    combine_keys.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down('r').perform()
```

So CONTROL + r works, but ALT + s command doesn't. It seems to be the exact same command, so not sure what's wrong with the ALT + s version.

Answer (score 0):

The IE browser shows the OS-native prompt to download the file.

Selenium is not capable to automate the file download prompt displayed by the IE browser.

So this can be the reason that your Selenium code is not working for downloading the file.

You need to handle this issue in a different way.

There are some third party libraries that can help you to automate the download prompt.

For java, python or Ruby, autoit or sikuli is  used most often.

So I suggest try to check those libraries and use the one that can server the purpose.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info, I was able to use pyautogui to send the shortcut instead to save the file.
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 's')

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding